# List of arrays/pointers c++

Tags: c++, arrays, list

I am inputting char arrays into a list. This is what i have so far

```
list<char*> l; 
char str[50];

cout<<"Enter strings. 0 to stop:\n";
while(1)
{
    cin >> str;
    if(strcmp(str, "0") == 0)
        break;

    l.push_back(str);
}

list<char*>::iterator p;

// display
for(p = l.begin() ; p != l.end(); p++)
    cout<<*p<<endl;
```

The display loop displays only the last entered string n times.
Is there a better way to represent a list of arrays?

Comment: Since arrays can't be copied in C++ a list of arrays is not allowed. You have a list of pointers which is not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 3):

It's doing exactly what you asked it to! Your list is an array of `char*` and you give it the same address every time. What is located at that address changes each time through the loop...

...And don't even think about returning that list from a function. The address in the list is only valid in the scope of the function call.

You'd be better off with something like `std::list<std::string>`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you always point to the same buffer `str`: if you want your list to contain different values, you'll need a different buffer for each entry. Of course, this quickly becomes hard to manage. Thus, you are much better off storing `std::string` objects in our list:

```
std::list<std::string> l;
for (std::string tmp; std::cin >> tmp; ) {
    if (tmp == "0") {
        break;
    }
    l.push_back(tmp);
}
```

Note that using `std::cin >> str;` as you do it is also highly dangerous: there is nothing which prevents the input from overflowing the buffer! **If** you use an input operator with a `char` buffer, make sure you set the stream's `width()` to the size of the buffer before doing so (`std::setw()` is declared in `<iomanip>`):

```
if (std::cin >> std::setw(sizeof(str)) >> str) {
    // ...
}
```

And, of course, you should check after each input that it was, indeed, successful.